# Rspec: Should be (this or that)

Tags: ruby, rspec

What would be the best way to write the rspec in a situation where either of two (or more) outcomes are acceptable?

Here's an example of what I want to do. This is obviously wrong (I think), but it should give you the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
it "should be heads or tails" do
  h="heads"
  t="tails"
  flip_coin.should be(h || t)
end
```

And yes, I'm aware I could write my own rspec matcher "should_be_one_or_the_other(option1,option2)", but that seems a bit much - I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

ActiveSupport provides `Object#in?` method. You can combine it with RSpec and simply use the following:

```
flip_coin.should be_in(["heads", "tails"])
```

Or with new Rspec 3 syntax:

```
expect(flip_coin).to be_in(["heads", "tails"])
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in the latest version, I had to turn it into an array first `be_in(["heads", "tails"])`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Minor correction: ActiveSupport defines `#in?` on `Object`, not on `Array`, since it's called like this `flip_coin.in? %w(heads tails)` and flip_coin can be any `Object`.

Answer (score 31):

I know this is old but in I ran into this on RSpec 3.4, there is an [`or` method](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/compound-expectations#use-%60or%60-to-chain-expectations) now.  So this is valid:

```
expect(flip_coin).to eq('heads').or(eq('tails'))
```

Answer (score 15):

I'd probably write something like this:

```
it "should be heads or tails" do
  ["heads", "tails"].should include flip_coin
end
```

Comment: A decent option, but it seems like it subverts the proper "rspec" way to do things, with the expected value on the right.

Comment: Left vs Right is a convention and this is an exception to that convention, the important part is  getting the `actual` and `expected` output statements correct. The output is correct with this format and that is what is most important:  `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected ["heads", "tails"] to include :unexpected_value.`

Answer (score 11):

Another way of writing it with the expectation on the right of the should:

```
it 'should be heads or tails' do
  flip_coin.should satisfy{|s| ['heads', 'tails'].include?(s)}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

if applied `or` with `be` matcher

```
expect(flip_coin).to eq('heads').or(be == 'tails')
```

Comment: I find this less intuitive than the answer using "or" from Dec '15.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by `flipping` the comparison:

`expect(['head','tails']).to include(flip_coin)`