# RSpec: String should be in array

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am testing a random string generator that takes two arrays of words and then picks random ones from them. I need to be able to test that it actually is random. For instance:

```
FrostyMeadow.generate(:nouns => ["hello", "world"], :adjectives => ["hello","world"]
```

should generate one of the following strings:

```
["hello world", "world world", "world hello", "hello hello"]
```

Is there any way to give rspec that array and check if the generated string is in there?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922346/rspec-should-be-this-or-that for some alternative answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Randomness is hard to test, but in your case you can achieve it this way:

```
word = FrostyMeadow.generate(:nouns => ["hello", "world"], :adjectives => ["hello","world"]
["hello world", "world world", "world hello", "hello hello"].should include(word)
```