# Does RSpec have a built in matcher for seeing if a String is one value or another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

**Edit:** Compound matcher answer provided is a much more elegant solution:

```
expect(@weathers.get_day_today).to eq('Today').or eq('Tonight')
```

**Original Question:**

I am testing if a value is either "Today" or "Tonight". Is there a built-in matcher? Or a cleaner method than what I'm doing?

**Edit:** The following was my attempt to do a custom test, but it doesn't work. Here's an example of what NOT to do.

First, add custom-matcher.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_this_or_that do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual == expected.first or expected.last
  end
end
```

Second, use it

```
expect(@weathers.get_day_today).to be_this_or_that(["Today", "Tonight"])
```

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143723/rspec-string-should-be-in-array. | [array].should include(word)

Comment: It's a different problem. My question isn't confined to using array as the matched value. M.Karim offered a better solution that's shorter and more elegant. Thanks.

Comment: `actual == expected.first or expected.last` this doesn't do what you think it does by the way.

Comment: @marflar You're right. I tested it on irb and it did't reply True or False. (though it returned a truthy object, hence it "worked") Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
expect(@weathers.get_day_today).to eq('Today').or eq('Tonight')
```

for more compound expectations you can visit [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/compound-expectations#use-%3Ccode%3Eor%3C/code%3E-to-chain-expectations).

Comment: pleasure is mine (y)