# Rspec: using OR in expect .to eq statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an rspec test where I want to ensure that only two values can be passed into my instance variable.  I noticed that `should satisfy` with a block seems to be the more accepted way to test where two outcomes are acceptable, but i'd like to implement an `expect().to eq()` as illustrated below:

```
it "only allows -2 or 2 as values" do
    expect (@note.value).to eq(2 or -2)
  end
```

Is this correct syntax for my desired rspec testing?  I understand the idea behind a `should` statement, and i'm more concerned with the idea as to why `should` is preferable (if that's actually the case) to using `expect .to eq` with compound expectations.

Thank you.

Comment: thanks.  I understand the `should` statement.  I'd like to know why the `expect .to eq` with compound expectations is presumably deficient to a `should` statement, though.

Comment: it's not. RSpec's `expect` syntax is now the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can `or` two matchers together:

```
expect(@note.value).to eq(2).or eq(-2)
```

For more info [see](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers/#compound-matcher-expressions).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922346/rspec-should-be-this-or-that), you could do it the other way round and have the possible values in the `expect` clause. With the [new matcher syntax](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) this would look like this:

```
expect([2, -2]).to include(@note.value)
```

I should also mention that you'll usually want to avoid this kind of randomness in your tests. Be precise about your expectations!

Comment: thanks, can you please expound on the randomness you see on my test?  I only want two values to pass true and everything else to return false.

Comment: You should be testing under which circumstances each specific value is returned - knowing that a method can return -2 or 2 is useless if it returns 2 instead of -2 for some input, or vice versa.

Comment: That's the randomness ;) Usually you'd test one specific note, where you're either sure that value is 2, or sure that the value is -2. Something along the lines of `expect(@first_note.value).to be(2); expect(@second_note.value).to be(-2)`